# Overload Generic Method for Specific Data Type

Tags: c#

I have method that transforms some input value by the user passing it a Func delegate wich returns the new value (very over simplified for what I am trying to achieve)

```
    public L Coerce<L>(string value, Func<string, L> coercer)
    {
        return coercer(value);
    }

    Coerce<int>("123", v => int.Parse(v));
```

This is fine however I also want to be able to write methods that override the behaviour for a specific type eg...

```
    public int Coerce<int>(string value)
    {
        return Coerce<int>(value, v => int.Parse(v));
    }
```

So basically calling

```
    Coerce<int>("123"); // equivalent Coerce<int>("123", v => int.Parse(v));
```

will save me having to re-write the int.Parse for every Coerce.  Of course this should then extend to handle

```
    public decimal Coerce<decimal>(string value)
    {
        return Coerce<decimal>(value, v => int.Parse(v));
    }
```

Etc etc.

Can this be done neatly?

James

Comment: You don't have to use the lambda-style calling: you could also call Coerce<int>("123", int.Parse).

Comment: OK that's a bit better but I'd prefer not to have to event add int.Parse at the end if possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you *really* don't want to do

```
Convert.ToInt32(value)
```

Then this will do what you are asking:

```
public T Coerce<T>(string value) where T : IConvertible
{
    return (T)(((IConvertible)value).ToType(typeof(T),
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Hence:

```
int x = Coerce<int>("123");
```

or

```
byte b = Coerce<byte>("123");
```

This will give you a compile-time error if you try to coerce to a non-convertible type, for example:

```
var x = Coerce<MyClass>("123"); //compile-time error
```

In which case you force the caller to use your `Coerce(string value, Func<string,T> coercer)` overload.

Comment: Edited to include `where T : IConvertible` keeping things a lot safer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a non-generic version:

```
public int CoerceInt32(string value)
{
    return Coerce(value, int.Parse);
}
```

Comment: Yes I could.  I suppose it would be the most straight forward approach but I was wondering If I could handle it a more "generic" way?

Comment: The reason for this is that I am actually doing this through extension methods and I don;t want to overrun the class with unnecessary methods (so sticking to one or two would be better in this case)

Comment: @kouPhax - Don't use generics if you don't have to - simpler is better!

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of this method?

Why do you want to write this:

```
int x = Coerce<int>("123", v => int.Parse(v));
```

instead of just this:

```
int x = int.Parse("123");
```

However, to answer your question, no, not "neatly". `.Parse` is a static method on the int and decimal types, and thus not available through your generic type.

The best you can hope for is to either write one overload per type you want to handle, or to write reflection code inside your method to figure out which static method to call.

And thus you get into a problem when you write this:

```
MyMagicType x = Coerce<MyMagicType>("123");
```

what then? Will you assume that MyMagicType has a .Parse method?

Comment: OK basically I am using extension methods on Controls.  I want to get the value using the Coerce function (the first example).  However if I am getting alot of decimals I don;t want to write control.Coerce<decimal>("Text", decimal.Parse) but rather control.Coerce<decimal>("Text").

Comment: But why not just write: decimal.Parse("Text")? that's the part I don't understand. What specifically do you want to gain by the Coerce method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid C# doesnt have template overriding like in C++. I came across a similar situation, and the way I had to work around it is to check the type at runtime:

```
public void DoStuff<T>(Dictionary<object, T> arg) {
    // ....
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ClassA)) {
        DoStuff((Dictionary<object, ClassA>)arg);
    }
    else (typeof(T) == typeof(ClassB)) {
        DoStuff((Dictionary<object, ClassB>)arg);
    }
    else {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be ClassA or ClassB");
    }
}
```